# run exe file on the internet

Tags: vb6

have developed vb6 project and my client want it to run on the internet in a week's time.
taking this project to web will take me almost five month to clear.is there a way that i can install dlls on the server and run exe file on the web/internet? please help me if it's possible

Comment: It is possible in theory for an application to output HTML (if that's what you mean), but not without a lot of work if your application is not a fully fledged web server in itself. You will need to add more detail about your application to get serious answers

Answer (score 2):

Only secure and fast solution is to use remote desktop connection to the application server.

- RDP / Terminal Server: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol
- Citrix: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrix_XenApp

But it's way better if you make your client spend more times to really upgrade the application for web usage.

Comment: +1 for looking for a solution instead of charging against a messy real world situation

Answer (score 0):

This depends how you have written the program.  If it's a standard windows form application the answer is no, you can't 'transplant' it.  If however it's a class that performs particular logic, you can do so. You will need to look at COM visibility because of your use of VB6. Can you give us more information about your project?

Edit:
You'll need to load your COM object into IIS and then call it. Without more information, I don't think we can help.  There are alternatives, like creating a .NET wrapper which can call and handle the object - but without an idea of what you have and final objective, this is tricky.  Sorry I can't be more help, please feel free to edit your first question if you have more information.

Comment: Thanks alot.user interface gets user input and send it to dll.is there away or tool to convert GUI of vb6 to vb.net

Comment: Can you post your entry-point on your VB6 .dll? I assume it doesn't have a GUI?

Comment: user interface is referenced to dll.so GUI will call certain function from  dll and pass desired parameters to the database and report back whether it's successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your dll is com dll that only runs on the server (not on client) it is possible to add it as a reference in a .net web application that use functionality from your dll.

Visual Studio automatically creates the wrappers needed to use it in .net when you add reference to your com dll.

In this scenario, you need to convert/rewrite the GUI from your exe to .NET web forms.

I think this will be the best compromise for your situation. If you have a lot of business code in you exe project, it might be a good idea to take that out in a VB6 dll project, stripping out all the GUI-part of the code, to minimize the work needed to convert code to .NET (so that you have only the GUI part in the .NET web application).

This approach will require NO extra work in your dlls unless they rely on GUI components.

Comment: It is not a big jump from VB6 to VB.NET. And if all the heavy functionality is just calls to the COM dll(s), and the GUI project is quite thin, it will not be too difficult to create the web GUI using Visual Studio and VB.NET. The visual design mode in Visual Studio for generating web forms is very easy to use. This will require NO changes to your existing dll's running on the server, and only GUI design to be re-drawn using Visual Studio.